# Can't find type [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount] when deploying script using Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a Powershell script version 5.1 that works when run using the Powershell Window, but get the following error when the script is run from a batch file.  I am trying to use proper typing for elements of a class I created.  I get the following error:

```
At C:\scripts\Upload_to_Orientation\TestStubs\myTest.ps1:76 char:3
+     [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount]$ADUser
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount].
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

I've tried adding the following, but the class is still not defined:

```
using assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management\v4.0_10.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.dll'
using namespace Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management
```

Here is a stripped down version of the script

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
#The following make no difference...
Import-module ActiveDirectory

class GenUser {
    [string]$Pwd 
    [string]$Status
    [string]$ErrMsg
    
    #[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$SPEmployee
    [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]$ADUser
    #[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount]$ADUser

    [string]$FirstName
    [string]$LastName
    [string]$Name
    [string]$DisplayName
    [string]$EmployeeNumber
    [string]$Email
    [string]$SamAccount

    GenUser([string]$first_name, [string]$last_name) {
        $n = $first_name + " " + $last_name
        $this.Status = "unknown"
        $this.ErrMsg = ""
        $this.FirstName = $first_name
        $this.LastName = $last_name
        $this.Name = $n
        $this.DisplayName = $n
        $this.Email = ""
        $this.SamAccount = ""
        $this.Pwd = ""
    }
    
    GenUser([Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]$AD_User) {
        $this.Status = $AD_User.Enabled
        $this.ErrMsg = ""
        #$this.ADUser = $AD_User
        $this.FirstName = $AD_User.GivenName
        $this.LastName = $AD_User.Surname
        $this.Name = $AD_User.Name
        $this.DisplayName = $AD_User.DisplayName
        $this.Email = $AD_User.UserPrincipalName
        $this.SamAccount = $AD_User.SamAccountName
        $this.Pwd = ""

    }

#Note: I stripped out most of my methods

}


[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
{
    $logfile = "C:\scripts\Upload_to_Orientation\TestStubs\myTest2.log"
    Write-Output "Starting myTest.ps1 ... " | Out-File $logfile -Encoding ASCII
    Write-Host "Starting..."

    Write-Output "PSVersion = $($PSVersionTable['PSVersion'])`r`n" | Out-File $logfile -Append -Encoding ASCII
    
    $test = [GenUser]::New("John", "Doe")
    
    Write-Output "Name = $($test.Name) " | Out-File $logfile -Append -Encoding ASCII


    Write-Output "Script completed ... " | Out-File $logfile -Append -Encoding ASCII
    Write-Host "Done..."
})
```

What am I missing?  It works fine when run from the Powershell window after I run "Import-Module ActiveDirectory", but I need to add the script to the Task Scheduler using a batch file to start the script so I can redirect errors to a second log file.

My batch file is:

```
cd C:\scripts\Upload_to_Orientation\TestStubs && powershell.exe -F .\myTest2.ps1 >m2.log  2>>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to launch your *PowerShell* script from a batch file. Launch it directly using *Task Scheduler*.

In task scheduler, in the *Actions* tab, click on button **New...**

[image: actions]

Then, in the *New Action* window, enter the path to the *PowerShell* executable, which is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

and in the *Add arguments* field, enter the full path to your *PowerShell* script.

[image]

If you want to set the working directory for your script, then enter it into the *Start in* field. Probably you should enter the path to the folder containing your *PowerShell* script in that field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried that, but I can't see any of the Powershell error messages that way.  The task completes, but none of my logging happens, so it must be failing even before the script has a chance to run.  Also, I did not get the expected result either.  Even in a new Powershell window I first need to run "Import-Module ActiveDirectory" before it will run.  I did notice that there is a short cut to:  "Active Directory for Windows PowerShell".  The script works on the commandline as expected.

Comment: I tried adding "-command Import-Module ActiveDirectory" to the task scheduler "Add arguments" as shown above, but that did not help.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Ralph can you [edit] your question and post the code of your _PowerShell_ script?